# How to play "D.S. al Fine" with A and B parts

Tags: notation, musical-forms, repeats

I have two pieces, in one of them there is an **A** part and a **B** part, and at the end it says **D.S al Fine**, (see below):
[image: Score of "Trio Premiär"]

My first question is:
How do I play this? (In what order?)

---

My second question is:
How do I play a piece with only **D.S al Fine** at the end? (In what order?)

Answer (score 5):

The 'A' and 'B' marks are there for navigation - there might be a rehearsal where you 'start at B', for instance. This piece obviously has other instruments playing, so marking A, B as well as bar numbers makes it easier to find places during rehearsals.

*D.S al Fine* here, in this piece, means play through everything, sequentially, and at the D.S., go back to the Segno (at A, as it happens), and play through until *Fine* - at the end of A.

Comment: In swedish: D.S. är förkortning av italienska Dal Segno. Så betydelsen blir "från tecknet till slut". I noterna finns ett Segno tecken, spela från  det till där det står Fine.

Comment: @ghellquist - it's all Dutch to me. Sorry, English (or French) is o.k.

Comment: my guess is that Sandra is from Sweden, all the text on the parti is in Swedish. I simply added a translation, no offense intended.